# Is there a normalized way to quote the Qur’an?

Tags: discussion, quran

Is there a standard and normalized way to correctly cite the Qur’an?
And especially to cite, not only the sorates but also the ayats?

Comment: I think this question was fine on the main site, it seems to be general and not specifically about how one should cite Quran on this site.